# Make CSS `text-align:center` Ignore Some Text

Tags: html, css

Here is what I've tried:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td > h4 {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    <h4>Hello</h4><sup>World</sup>
  </td>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the browser centers both "Hello" and "World" together. How can I center ONLY "Hello" (but still have "World" follow it)?

Comment: Update your question to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), otherwise it's [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some very simple CSS:

```
sup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
}
```

The idea is to force a width of 0, but allow it to overflow. (You can't set a width on an `inline` element, so we use `inline-block` instead)

You can see the full example in a snippet below:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Relevant CSS */
sup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4 style="display: inline;">Hello</h4><sup>World</sup>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda funky, but gets you your result. This will only be okay if you have static values for your font size and `td` widths. Otherwise the browser will show the `<sup>` text overflowing into the next cell.

```css
table td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

h4 {
  position: relative;
  }
h4 sup {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left 100%;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some
    </td>
    <td>
      Other
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Hello<sup>World</sup></h4>      
    </td>
    <td>
      Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```